# What is the best (offline) way to convert a big PDF into Word file (excluding images)?

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, microsoft-word-2007

What is the best way to convert a big PDF into Word file (excluding images)?

PDF has many images but in converted Word file i don't want those images, means in conversion process i want to exclude images. but i need text in same formatting like PDF.

Any online tool will not work because PDF is too big. and i need instant result. don't wan to upload PDF and get in email.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are some free tools around but they don't seem to work fine. IMO, the best offline way to convert your PDF documents into MS Word format is to use [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/). Another good alternative is [OmniPage](http://www.nuance.com/imaging/omnipage/omnipage-standard.asp).

Comment: Adobe Acrobat gives error almost on all files which i want to convert and I think it's because of images. I don't need images can i exclude images in PDF to word conversion process in Adobe Acrobat 8?

Comment: I guess Acrobat has no option to exclude images. There is another alternative (pdf2word) which supports deletion of graphics and pictures from the generated Word document. It's a shareware as well. Link: http://www.verypdf.com/pdf2word/index.html

Comment: Adobe Acrobat X v.10.1.18 worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't dead-set on work, [pdftohtml](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) works pretty well, and you could convert the html file to word if you really need a .doc file.
It's a little out of date, but assuming your pdf isn't using the bleeding-edge aspects of the file-format, it will probably work.

If it is a really recent pdf, there is [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html). It doesn't preserve as much of the formatting, but it should handle anything.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded pdf2word software. it is a trail version works for 100 times. it is converting only first five pages and prompt us to purchase the software to convert without limitations.

Comment: Well, at least tell us where to get the software. And does it work as described? What degree of quality are you getting, etc…?